# Overlay lines with a varying number of points from a list using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to plot multiple lines with a varying number of points per line, with different colors using ggplot2. My MWE is given by

```
test <- list()
length(test) <- 10
for(i in 1:10){
  test[[i]] <- rnorm(100 - i) # Note - different number of points per line!!!!
}
```

Note that The length for each vector in list are different. Then, is not possible to transform in data.frame.

Comment: You have to convert your data from "wide form" to "long form" in order to do this. This will require the addition of an identifier for each stream. Probably the most confusing thing about `ggplot` is that this has to be done, and it is not really trivial until you have done it a half dozen times or so.

Comment: What have you tried so far? There is a lot of similar questions here.

Comment: Of course neither of those are particularly suitable because he is starting with his data in a list - with potentially different numbers of points per list, not a data frame. All the easy ways to go from wide to long assume a dataframe.

Comment: The length for each vector in list are different. Then, is not possible to transform in `data.frame`.

Comment: You can create `test` without any `for` loop in a one-liner: `set.seed(1234L); test <- lapply(100L - 1:10, rnorm)`. Note the use of `set.seed()` to ensure reproducible random data.

Comment: Note that the "linked duplicate" does not address or answer this question.

Comment: @MikeWise Thanks for editing the Q. Now it's obvious i'ts not a dupe. I've voted to reopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there were some remarks about the for loops, here is an alternate and more sophisticated approach in a modern idiom (i.e. `purrr` from the tidyverse).

- Creates an id vector as a factor (`ids`) so as to avoid warnings about combining levels later.
- Sets up a function (`mkdf`) to make a data frame from an id variable and a vector of data.
- Uses `map2` from `purrr` to merge `ids` and the original data list with `mkdf`
- Uses `bind_rows` from `dplyr` to merge the resulting list of data frames into one.
- Plots it.

The code:

```
library(tidyr)

# dummpy up some wide data (but of different lengths) in a **list** of curves
test <- list()
for(i in 1:5){
  test[[i]] <- rnorm(10 - i) 
}

# helper data (could do inline, but it would be harder to read)
ids <- as.factor(sprintf("id-%d",1:length(test)))             # curve ids as factors
mkdf <- function(x,y) data.frame(xx=1:length(x),yy=x,key=y)   # makes into dataframe

df <- test %>% map2(ids,mkdf) %>%  bind_rows()   #single pipe using purrr and dplyr

# plot it
ggplot(df) + geom_line(aes(x=xx,y=yy,color=key))
```

A plot. I reduced the datasizes to make it easier to see:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

So this gets you want you want I think. Note that it works on your list that has a different number of points per vector - which of course is one main reason why one would a list instead of a dataframes.

Most if not all of the examples on SO for this scenario are working with dataframes instead of data in lists. Since the vectors have different lengths, links that address this by melting a dataframe to a long form do not apply.

However if you did happen to have a dataframe, which implies a set of vectors of the same length, then you could use `melt`. However using `gather` from `tidyr` would probably be a more modern idiom for this than `melt` from `reshape2`. Note that `melt` can also be used on lists, although I would have to research how it handles the id.

I also choose not to use a function from the `lapply` class because I wanted to emphasis the "wide data" to "long data" aspect - something I think a for loop does far better that `lapply`, which beginning users can find mysterious.

Anyway we should probably be using something from `purrr` now as that is a modern type-stable functional library.

Here is some code - using a `for` loop, so not the most compact, but unrolled to make it easy and quick to understand:

```
library(ggplot2)
test <- list()
length(test) <- 10
for(i in 1:10){
  test[[i]] <- rnorm(100 - i) 
}

# Convert data to long form
df <- NULL
for(i in 1:10){
  ydat <- test[[i]]
  ndf <- data.frame(key=paste0("id",i),x=1:length(ydat),y=ydat)
  df <- rbind(df,ndf)
}

# plot it
ggplot(df) + geom_line(aes(x=x,y=y,color=key))
```

Yielding:

[image]

Comment: `n <- sequence(10); ind <- 100 - n; df <- data.frame(id = rep(n, ind), x = sequence(ind), y = rnorm(sum(ind)))`

Comment: Like @rawr I was puzzled why question and answer both used clumsy `for` loops although R has neat functions. `type`can be created in a one-liner: `set.seed(1234L); test <- lapply(100L - 1:10, rnorm)`. To reshape `test` from wide to a long form which is suitable for `ggplot2` we can use `df <- data.frame(id = rep(seq_along(test), lengths(test)), x = sequence(lengths(test)), y = unlist(test))`.

Comment: Of course I am aware of `lapply` and I use it all the time, but I didn't think it was appropriate to use it here. The user posed the question using a `for` loop, which led me to believe that he might not be familiar with `lapply`. I felt a `for` loop would have higher didactic value - since the main lesson I am trying to get across is the need to go from wide(ish) data to long data when using `ggplot2`, which is of course the main hurdle to using `ggplot` for beginners. One lesson at a time. And `for` loops are not that terrible, although the downvoter apparently thinks so.

Comment: And the linked duplicate is for `melt` applied to a dataframe, clearly not what we have here.

Comment: Anyway, why don't you post your approach as a solution? Starting with his data of course. I don't see you using anything related to the "duplicate link" by the way.

Comment: @MikeWise Please can you explain your last sentence: _I don't see you using anything related to the "duplicate link" by the way._ I simply haven't understood what you mean. Thank you.

Comment: I just meant that your suggested answer (which is nice - and I would like to see posted) does not use any techniques from the duplicate link.

Answer (score 2):

As already pointed out by [Mike Wise](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3458744/mike-wise) in his [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44346483/3817004), `gplot2` requires a data.frame as input, preferably in *long format*.

However, both question and accepted answer used `for` loops although R has neat functions. To create the `test` data set, the following "one-liner" can been
used:

```
set.seed(1234L)   # required to ensure reproducible data
test <- lapply(100L - 1:10, rnorm)
```

instead of

```
test <- list()
length(test) <- 10
for(i in 1:10){
  test[[i]] <- rnorm(100 - i) 
}
```

Note the use of `set.seed()` to ensure *reproducible random data*.

To reshape `test` from wide to long form, the whole list is turned into a data.frame at once using `unlist()`, adding the additional columns as required:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = rep(seq_along(test), lengths(test)),
  x = sequence(lengths(test)),
  y = unlist(test)
)
```

instead of turning each list element into a separate small data.frame and incrementally appending the pieces to a target data.frame using a `for` loop.

The plot is then created by

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df) + geom_line(aes(x = x, y = y, color = as.factor(id)))
```

---

Alternatively, the `melt()` function has a method for lists:

```
library(data.table)
long <- melt(test, measure.vars = seq_along(test))
setDT(long)[, rn := rowid(L1)] # add row numbers for each group
ggplot(long) + aes(x = rn, y = value, color = as.factor(L1)) + geom_line()
```

Comment: I like that one step dataframe creation using elementry base-R function (well, except `unlist` I guess, but still).